# IISRESET corrects my icons - but why?

Tags: sql, .net, iis

I host a website that has an issue randomly, once in a blue moon the images on the buttons will change to red Xs. After a bit of playing with it I found that recycling iis corrects the issue but can someone explain to me why? I have the IIS pool set to recycle every night at 1 am automatically. It does not happen in the middle of the day and it only seems to happen after the pool recycles.

Answer (score 0):

Check this issue with firebug. If your Situation occures, check the headers from your srver for the images. Then post the headers here again.

Additional have a look into the logs. What does the logs say? 404 (File not found) or what?

Without These information, it´s hard to solve ...